# Why do we write onload() function before we write send() in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am new to XMLHttpRequest. I dont understand why do we write onload() function before send() function. onload() function process the response what we receive and send() function sends a request to server. So onload() has to be written after send() function as per my understanding. Can somebody help to understand this.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  method = 'GET',
  url = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/';

xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
xmlhttp.onload = function () {
  // Do something with the retrieved data
};
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: You are declaring the onload function, not invoking it. You may consider reading a bit more about javascript functions, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I dont understand why do we write `onload()` function before `send()` function.

So that the load handler is in place *before* the request is sent, since sending the request will result in calling the handler (if successful).

> `onload()` function process the response what we receive and `send()` function sends a request to server. So `onload()` has to be written after `send()` function as per my understanding.

It's **called** after `send` is called (by the XHR infrastructure) (or potentially during). When you assign it to `onload`, you're not *calling* it. You're just defining it so that it's there when XHR needs to call it.

Here's what happens:

1. You create the XHR.
2. You register a handler for its `load` event (in your case, by assigning a function to `onload`).
3. You call `send`.

   1. The browser starts (and potentially finishes) the request
4. When the request finishes, if it's successful, the browser's XHR handling triggers the `load` event. That looks for any currently-registered handlers for `load` and queues calls to those handlers, if any. Those calls are run as soon as the main JavaScript thread is available to run them.

Very often, you'd get away with doing it the wrong way around because by the time the request completes, you'll have put the `load` handler there; but not ***always***. `load` is an event. If the request can be satisfied immediately (for instance, from cache), the browser *could* fire `load` during `send`, and look to see if there's any `load` handler *during* the call to `send`, and if there isn't, not queue a call to any callback. Later when you attach a handler, the event has already been fired (when none were attached).

So you have to attach the handler before calling `send`.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder: So am i allowed to write send() before onload(). Will it cause any issue on my application.

Comment: @user2613946: I don't know where in my original answer you thought you read that. Hopefully the updated answer makes it clearer: No, you cannot reliably connect your `load` handler *after* calling `send`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder +1 for the awesome explanation.Just want to know, the jquery ajax worked in the same way, isn't it ?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna: Yes, but traditionally since the call to start it was also the call where handlers were hooked up, there wasn't a problem. When they updated jQuery to support adding handlers via a Promise-like chain (early "Deferred"s), that meant inherently the handlers were hooked up afterward. They had to make sure they handled that, by triggering the callback if the "Deferred" was already resolved when you added your handler for it. (Sadly, they did this wrong to start with, but it's been sorted out since.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, hi I am new at JavaScript and I just need your clarification. So, we need to put onload before send since it is POSSIBLE that during  send a browser will fire onload. Is that correct? Thank you

Comment: @mirzhal - I do, for that reason. Whether browsers actually will I don't know. After the whole `img` thing I'd tend to think they'd probably avoid making that possible, but I don't know. But in the modern world, just use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if `onload` event is hit & no assigned handler is found, why doesn't the browser clear / consume the event, but just leave it there ?

Comment: @Grace - I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean if mistakenly assigning `onload` event handler after calling `send();`, immediately after `send();`, the response comes back (`onload` event is hit) but `onload` event handler is not yet assigned. You explained that `Later when you attach a handler, the event has already been fired (when none were attached).` My question is when browser can't find the handler, why it doesn't clear the triggered `onload` event (here I mean browser claims current event is settled) without running callback (since no callback is setup)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder (cont')  If doing so, no outstanding unhandled event, so when `Later when you attach a handler`, the handler should not fire due to previous event trigger as you said.

Comment: @Grace - I'm still not following you. There's nothing special going on here. If you don't attach the handler, and you call `send`, and the work is immediately done, the event fires. If there's no handler there to receive it, that's that. Later if you add a handler, it'll never get called. The browser doesn't keep the response so it can give it to a handler that's attached **later**. In any case, in 2023, the answer is: Don't use XHR at all, use `fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

xhr.onload is an event handler that is set to a function. This function will be called when the HTTP request completes successfully. The onload event is typically triggered when the entire HTTP response has been received.

```js
   document.getElementById('get-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');

xhr.responseType = 'json';

xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(xhr.response);
};

xhr.send();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Get data from server</h1>
        <button id="get-button">Get Data</button>

        <script src="style.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```