# Can't get every button to update, only the first button gets updated with JavaScript & AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have created my own "like" button. With AJAX I'm able to post changes to database to add 1 to the "like" button. Then JavaScript will update the first "like" button with the updated information once. It will not update again if I click the "like" again. Also none of other "like" buttons work, they only refresh the page.

I have searched all over trying to find an answer for this. I have gotten it down to where I have each like button to where it has its own id. Even though I'm passing the id for the button into AJAX and back to JavaScript from the server. I'm still not able to update the other "like" buttons. Only the first one and only once.

```js
<html>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  function sendData() {
    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Bind the FormData object and the form element
    var FD = new FormData(form);

    XHR.onload = () =>{
     var response
     try{
     response = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
     }catch (e){
      console.error('no parse');
     }
     if(response){
      handleresponse(response);
     }
    }
    // Set up our request
    XHR.open("POST", "likes.php");

    // The data sent is what the user provided in the form
    XHR.send(FD);

   
  }
 
  // Access the form element...
  
  var form = document.getElementById("likesform");

  // ...and take over its submit event.
  form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    sendData();
  });
});
function handleresponse(response){
 console.log(response.message);
 let value = response.message;
 let id = response.id;
 console.log(id);
 document.getElementById(id).value = "Liked " + value;
 value = 0;
 id = 0;
}
</script>
```

```html
<?php

function postcommentbar($imagenumber, $likes, $num_rows){




 echo "<div id='postcommentbar'>";
 echo "<form id='likesform' ><input type='hidden' name='imagenumber' value='".$imagenumber."'><input type='hidden' name='like' value='Like'><input type='hidden' name='likes' value='".$likes."'><input type='submit' class='likebutton' id='".$imagenumber."'  value='Like ".$likes."'></form>";

 echo "<form action='comments.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='imagenumber' value='".$imagenumber."'><input id='commentbutton' type='submit' name='comment' value='Comment ".$num_rows."'></form>";
 echo "</div>";
 $num_rows = 0;
 
}

?>
```

I expect to be able to click any "like" button on the page and see it updated accordingly with the increased number of "like"s.

Could you please advise me on how I can achieve this?

I have onload before send.  If you look at the code you wool see this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we write onload() function before we write send() in XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346547/why-do-we-write-onload-function-before-we-write-send-in-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested that you are using the imagenumber as identifier.I have updated my code and this should work with your code.

I have implemented php code to dynamically generate numbers and bind them to get unique names and then send them to the sendData function.This code executes well at my end.

Please have a look, if this helps

```
<body>
<?php 
    for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
        ?>
        <div>
    <form id='likesform<?= $i ?>' ><input type='hidden' name='imagenumber' value='imagenumber<?= $i ?>'><input type='hidden' name='like' value='Like'>
        <input type='hidden' name='likes' value='adas'><input type='button' class='likebutton' id='imagenumber<?= $i ?>'  value='Like' onclick="sendData('likesform<?= $i ?>')">
    </form>
</div>
        <?php
    }
?>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sendData(form_id){
    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var form = document.getElementById(form_id);
    var FD = new FormData(form);
    XHR.onload = () =>{
        var response
        console.log(XHR.responseText);
        try{
        response = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
        }catch (e){
            console.error('no parse');
        }
        if(response){
            handleresponse(response);
        }
    }
    // Set up our request
    XHR.open("POST", "likes.php");

    // The data sent is what the user provided in the form
    XHR.send(FD);
}

function handleresponse(response){
    // console.log(response.message);
    let value = response.message;
    let id = response.id;
    console.log(id);
    document.getElementById(id).value = "Liked " + value;
    value = 0;
    id = 0;
}
</script>
```

I also created a file named "likes.php".This is the output which i sent from the file and appended it with the DOM.

```
<?php 
echo json_encode(array('message' => 1, 'id' => $_POST['imagenumber']));
?>
```

Update your function with the below one.I have made some changes to your html binding.The problem was you were not escaping the quotes properly.
Try with this function, this will work.

```
<?php
function postcommentbar($imagenumber, $likes, $num_rows){
echo "<div id='postcommentbar'>"; echo "<form id='".$imagenumber."' ><input type='hidden' name='imagenumber' value='".$imagenumber."'><input type='hidden' name='like' value='Like'><inputtype='hidden' name='likes' value='".$likes."'><input type='button' class='likebutton' id='".$imagenumber."' onclick=\"sendData('$imagenumber')\" value='Like ".$likes."'></form>";
}
?>
```

This code does not generates any syntax errors at my end.

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: <?php
function postcommentbar($imagenumber, $likes, $num_rows){
 echo "<div id='postcommentbar'>";
 echo "<form id='".$imagenumber."' ><input type='hidden' name='imagenumber' value='".$imagenumber."'><input type='hidden' name='like' value='Like'><input type='hidden' name='likes' value='".$likes."'><input type='button' class='likebutton' id='".$imagenumber."' onclick='sendData('".$imagenumber."')' value='Like ".$likes."'></form>";
?>
}

Comment: i think my main issue is that the button is inside a php function. This allows me to call the like button over and over again for each post that is pulled out of the database. I think this is where im running into the synatx error of ending unexpectedly..

Comment: also below this like form is another form for comments.php. they all reside inside the same div.

Comment: I have added something to this answer.Please have a look

Comment: i have one more question. document.getElementById(id).value = "Liked " + value; It is not updating on the screen.

Comment: nevermind i figured it out. You have to have atleast one letter before you have a number in the id of an element.
 id='like".$imagenumber."'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple forms with multiple like buttons?
If yes then you cannot use the same id for multiple forms.ID has to be unique in a DOM. That's the first issue with your code.

The second thing is when you are sending data through ajax, due to the same form name it will always consider the last form data with the id "likesform", because you are using static id, that's the second issue.

Anyways this issue are only relevant if you have multiple forms on a single page, and i do think you have multiple forms.

Now solution for your problem.

Why use the event listener when you can add a onclick function to the element itself during rendering the elements.Until and unless you are doing that for some purpose!

Have a look to the code below.

```js
function sendData(id, form_id){
    console.log("Called");
  var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var form = document.getElementById(form_id);
  var FD = new FormData(form);
     XHR.onload = () =>{
      var response
      try{
      response = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
      }catch (e){
       console.error('no parse');
      }
      if(response){
       handleresponse(response);
      }
     }
     // Set up our request
     XHR.open("POST", "likes.php");

     // The data sent is what the user provided in the form
     XHR.send(FD);
 }
  
  function handleresponse(response){
 console.log(response.message);
 let value = response.message;
 let id = response.id;
 console.log(id);
 document.getElementById(id).value = "Liked " + value;
 value = 0;
 id = 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div>
  <form id='likesform' ><input type='hidden' name='imagenumber' value='"asdadddd"'><input type='hidden' name='like' value='Like'>
   <input type='hidden' name='likes' value='adas'><input type='button' class='likebutton' id='id1'  value='Like' onclick="sendData('id1','likesform')">
  </form>
 </div>
 <div>
  <form id='likesform1' ><input type='hidden' name='imagenumber' value='"asdadddd"'><input type='hidden' name='like' value='Like'>
   <input type='hidden' name='likes' value='adas'><input type='button' class='likebutton' id='id2'  value='Like' onclick="sendData('id2','likesform1')">
  </form>
 </div>
 <div>
  <form id='likesform2' ><input type='hidden' name='imagenumber' value='"asdadddd"'><input type='hidden' name='like' value='Like'>
   <input type='hidden' name='likes' value='adas'><input type='button' class='likebutton' id='id3'  value='Like' onclick="sendData('id3','likesform2')">
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
```

Explanation to the code.
I have removed the onload eventListener as there is no need to add a function inside the listener.

This is because a function is compiled and only runs when you call them, so there is no risk of it being called before the DOM or any elements render.

I have created multiple forms and buttons with different id, that are then supplied to the sendData function as parameters.

The id from that parameter is then  used to pull the data from relevant form.You also have the id of the button being clicked, which you can further use to manipulate the button value.

I have also changed the input type="submit" to type="button" which will not reload the page and we wont have to use event.preventDefault.

You can further process your required functionality once you receive the response.

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: I appreciate the help. What you laid out makes more sense. However im getting an unexpected end of input error. Any ideas?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
Thats all it says

Comment: Would be helpful to understand if you also share your updated code.

Comment: If you have updated the code with your dynamic values and you are passing the string values in the onclick function, then you will have to add those into the single or double quotes explicitly.

Comment: i changed everything to take my variables to asign id's for the form and to the id. actually i can probably get away with just the form id because it will be $imagenumber. This is also the id for the button i want to update the value on. So id in sendData(id,form_id) really isnt needed. Aslong as the imagenumber is being passed i can always call back on the id of the button.

Comment: Once I figure out this one issue i will accept your advice as the answer.  Appreciate your effort.

Comment: Appreciate that @JohnKemper. Also have a look at the updated answer which i posted.That should save you some time.It has php logic implemented as well.